# How to log or dump raw JSON messages with SignalR - Protocol JSON (Hub)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

How to get dump of all messages (raw payload) that are traveling between client <> server ? I tried to configure logging verbosity for following namespaces, without any success..

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.*
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.*
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.Transports.WebSocketsTransport.*
```

A lots of information, but all I got is :

```
DefaultHubDispatcher - Received hub invocation: InvocationMessage { InvocationId: "0", Target: "sendMessage", Arguments: [ System.Collections.Generic.List`1[  MyMessageHubType  ] ], StreamIds: [  ] }.
```

I tried to override ToString() on MyMessageHubType, nu success ..

Any clues ? Somebody managed to accomplish this ?

Comment: It seems to be by design. A workaround is that you could pass a logger instance to the Hub and add the message got in the hub into the applicationLog , refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689026/how-to-pass-logger-into-signalr-hub-on-server-side-in-asp-net-core-application).

Comment: The refering thread uses string as  a signature. I'm using strongly typed message (POCO) object in hub's  SendMessage and I would like to see original messages before deserialization failed.

Comment: Did you found anything on this topic ? I've been searching a lot but i didnt found any solution to this.

Comment: No i did not. Added a custom logger to dump messages. But aspnetcore logs are still useful in case incoming traffic has invalid json messages, because parse and serialization errors describe what went wrong.